# Opening word document, copying specific text, paste into excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to make a VBA script that opens a word document, looks for a word that looks like "TPXXXX" where "X" are numbers, and then pastes that text into an excel spreadsheet. I can open up the word document, but I am having trouble selecting and finding the text I need. So far for that part I have:

```
Sub Copy()

'Create variables
Dim Word As New Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
Dim Doc_Path As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WB_Name As String

Doc_Path = "C:\Path\To\File.docx"
Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc_Path)

'Find text and copy it (part that I am having trouble with)
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "TP"
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.EscapeKey
Selection.MoveLeft Unit: wdCharacter , Count:=2
Selection.MoveRight Unit: wdCharacter , Count:=4
Selection.Copy

'Open excel workbook and paste
WB_Name = Application.GetOpenFilename(",*.xlsx")
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(WB_Name)

WB.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
WordDoc.Close
Word.Quit

End Sub
```

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Excel version:

```
Sub CopyTPNumber()

    'Create variables
    Dim Word As New Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
    Dim r As Word.Range
    Dim Doc_Path As String
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WB_Name As String

    Doc_Path = "C:\temp\TestFind.docx"
    Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc_Path)
    ' Set WordDoc = ActiveDocument

    ' Create a range to search.
    ' All of content is being search here
    Set r = WordDoc.Content

    'Find text and copy it (part that I am having trouble with)
    With r
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        With .Find
            .Text = "TP[0-9]{4}"
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
        End With
        .Copy
        ' Debug.Print r.Text
    End With


    'Open excel workbook and paste
    WB_Name = Excel.Application.GetOpenFilename(",*.xlsx")
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(WB_Name)

    WB.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("AB2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    WordDoc.Close
    Word.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfect! Do you know how I would go about creating a loop for it to find all TP numbers?

Comment: Instead of `.Execute` you can do a loop: `Do While .Execute`. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1009085/find-all-instances-of-a-text-and-make-it-a-hyperlink-with-a-macro) for an example.

Comment: One more thing, how would I stop the loop if there are no more TPXXXX numbers anymore? The amount of TP numbers varies from each document I have to copy them from, and the only thing I can think of is maybe counting the amount of TP numbers and then using a For loop to iterate that many times.

Comment: When there are no more matches, `Find.Execute` will return a `False`, so the `Do While .Execute` loop will terminate. The loop should execute once for each successful find. All the actions you want to occur on each Find match should be inside the `Do While ...` loop.

Comment: What would the condition look like? Would it be: Do While .Execute(.Text = "TP[0-9]{4}" .......) = true?

Comment: You should be able to call Do While .Execute with no parameters. All parameters for Find can be set before the Do While loop. So replace .Execute in the code in the proposed answer with (a) a `Do While .Execute` statement, (b) statements inside the loop that carry out the copy/paste of data, (c) a `Loop` statement to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "TP[0-9]{4}"
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
End With
Selection.Copy
```

I've used wildcard matching `.MatchWildcards = True`. The pattern to match is specified by `.Text = "TP[0-9]{4}"` --- match "TP" followed by *exactly* four digits. If the number of digits varies in your application, replace `{4}` with say `{3,5}`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Oops --- the above code snippet runs from within Word, but not from Excel. See below for the Excel version.

Comment: How is VBA code different when switching between Excel and Word?

Comment: If the VBA code is running from Word, you can access the `Selection` object in Word; if running from Excel, there's no access to Word's `Selection` (at least I don't know how to do it). That's why I used a `Word.Range` object.